# How to correctly implement kendo-switch angular component? (It doesn't correctly render "checked" state)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular-cli

I have a new Angular 4 project using CLI, and have other Kendo UI components working.  While using kendo-switch, when checked=true, the switch does not toggle correctly.  Rather than throw from left (off) to right (on), it just turns the toggle color to themed color (orange = default).

[This plunker shows the toggle working fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview), but [my code in this github repo](https://github.com/abcox/ng-kendo-demo) does not.

I have included the node modules to support this component, but it does not render correctly.  I also am using SASS to load the default Kendo UI theme.

Other components work, but kendo-switch does not render correctly.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.04.6",
  "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^2.0.0",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.3.1",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.2.2",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.3.2",   // <-- npm install
  "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.2.2",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.4",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^1.0.3",
  "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.43.2",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.12.6",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
  "tslint": "~5.7.0",
  "typescript": "^2.3.4"
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';   // <-- import the module
import { LabelModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-label';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,

    ButtonsModule,
    DateInputsModule,
    DropDownsModule,
    InputsModule,   // <-- import module
    LabelModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<form class="k-form">

  <!-- kendo-datepicker control works -->

  <label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Birth Date</span>
    <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
  </label>

  <!-- kendo-switch controls (NOT CORRECTLY RENDERING WHEN "CHECKED") -->

  <label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Newsletter Signup</span>
    <
      [(ngModel)]="newsletter"
      [onLabel]="'Yes'"
      [offLabel]="'No'"
      [disabled]="false"
      >
    </kendo-switch>
  </label>

  <!-- kendo-autocomplete control works -->

  <label class="k-form-field">
    <span>City</span>
    <kendo-autocomplete
          [data]="items"
          [placeholder]="'e.g. Toronto'">
      </kendo-autocomplete>
  </label>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Newsletter Signup</span>
      <
       [(ngModel)]="newsletter"
       [onLabel]="'Yes'"
       [offLabel]="'No'"
       [disabled]="false"
       >
      </kendo-switch>
 </label>
```

to

```
 <label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Newsletter Signup</span>
    <kendo-switch
       [(ngModel)]="newsletter"
       [onLabel]="'Yes'"
       [offLabel]="'No'"
       [disabled]="false"
      >
    </kendo-switch>
  </label>
```

This should work

U missed Kendo-switch at the open brace